# Manual filter generation in HP ALM Quality Center

Tags: ota, hp-alm

Filters in QC can be copied to clipboard and pasted from it.

```
[Filter]{
TableName:CYCLE,
ColumnName:CY_FOLDER_ID,
LogicalFilter:\0000004a\^Root\Sprint1^ Or ^Root^ Or ^Root\Sprint2\QA\Func\Columns ordering^,
VisualFilter:\0000004a\^Root\Sprint1^ Or ^Root^ Or ^Root\Sprint2\QA\Func\Columns ordering^,
NO_CASE:
}
{
FLT:[X],
TYPE:TESTSET-TSTEST,
EXISTS_IN_IDS:Y,
IN_IDS:\000000ad\[Filter]{
TableName:TESTCYCL,
ColumnName:TC_STATUS,
LogicalFilter:\0000001a\"Blocking Fail" Or Blocked,
VisualFilter:\0000001a\"Blocking Fail" Or Blocked,
NO_CASE:
}

}
```

I'm trying to generate such filter in my own application. The problem is that I don't know how 0000004a, 0000001a and 000000ad are generated. When I replace filter values with other values the filter doesn't work anymore. It needs those HEX values to be recalculated.

Does anyone know what is the algorithm of generating that values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mentioned items are the lengths of the according filter.text - string in hex

Comment: Could you please check your grammar and spelling. It took me 10 times to read your little answer to finally understand it. xD